# How do I find all nodes which shares at least n nodes with a given node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

The title is a bit of a mess, but I have an image which accurately describes what I'm trying to achieve.

As an example, I'm working in neo4j's sandbox, with the Movies-dataset.

The task: **Find all actors that have worked on a movie with Tom Hanks more than twice (3 or more times).**

Here's the query (and result) which shows all actors that have worked with him at all, and the movies they've been part of.

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person) 
RETURN m, p2
```

[image: neo4jgraph]

To save you some time, the only person who has worked with Tom at least thrice (3 times) is Meg Ryan to the right.

---

So, as a freshman at this query language, my immediate thought was to try the following Cypher-query:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person)
    WHERE count(m) > 2
RETURN p2, m
```

This gave an error, telling me that I can't put the `count`-function there.

---

I've also tried using the `WITH`-keyword:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person)
    WITH p1, m, p2, count(m) AS common_movie_count
    WHERE common_movie_count > 2
RETURN DISTINCT p2, m
```

...but that didn't help me much, and although it did run, it gave me an empty output (meaning no matches).

---

For some reason I was allowed to get the names of relevant actors (and the count), as long as I accept getting ALL actors, in table format.

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person)
RETURN DISTINCT p2.name AS name, count(m) as common_movie_count
ORDER BY common_movie_count DESC
```

This query returned the following table (or started with these three results):
| name           | common_movie_count |
| -------------- | ------------------ |
| "Meg Ryan"     | 3                  |
| "Ron Howard"   | 2                  |
| "Gary Sinise"  | 2                  |

I want the nodes, not just the name. Also: I only want the nodes that are relevant (`count > 3`), as in the dataset I intend to apply this, there will be too many non-relevant nodes to apply this to them all.

---

Do you have any ideas or simple solutions to my problem? To me the problems seems so simple that I can't be the first one to run into it, but I can't seem to google my way to a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close here:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person)
    WITH p1, m, p2, count(m) AS common_movie_count
    WHERE common_movie_count > 2
RETURN DISTINCT p2, m
```

except that the `m` in the `WITH` statement makes `common_movie_count` always return 0

If you do this:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-->(m:Movie)<--(p2:Person)
    WITH p1, p2, COLLECT( DISTINCT m) AS common_movies
    WHERE SIZE(common_movies) > 2
UNWIND common_movies AS m
RETURN p2, m
```

you would get the expected result

Comment: Thank you so much, this solves my problem perfectly! Do you happen to have any good resources which explains the behavior in simple terms?